# DropDownList with UpdatePanel not changing the html "selected" attribute

Tags: javascript, asp.net, drop-down-menu, updatepanel, asmx

I was playing around with WebMethods when I came across this issue.

I wanted to create a simple calculator using WebMethod and javascript, but it will only work if the options of the DDL have the "selected" attribute in the source within the browser. If I remove the UpdatePanel this works fine; the page is refreshed and the html source code will display a "selected" attribute on whatever I chose within the DDL. With the UpdatePanel, only the first option is selected (by default). The issue is that I don't want whole page to refresh.

Here's my code:

```
<input id="TextA" type="text" />
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <triggers>
      <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DropDownList1" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
    </triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
      <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
        onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True">
        <asp:ListItem Value="+">+</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="-">-</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="/">/</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="*">*</asp:ListItem>
      </asp:DropDownList>
    </ContentTemplate>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
  <input id="TextB" type="text" />
```

The WebMethod:

```
[WebMethod]
public string Add(double a, double b) 
{
  double Calc = a + b;
  //string StringCalc = Calc.ToString();
  string Complete = "The answer is " + Calc;
  return Complete;
}
[WebMethod]
public string Subtract(double a, double b)
{
  double Calc = a - b;
  string Complete = "The answer is " + Calc;
  return Complete;
}
[WebMethod]
public string Divide(double a, double b)
{
  double Calc = a / b;
  string Complete = "The answer is " + Calc;
  return Complete;
}
[WebMethod]
public string Multiply(double a, double b)
{
  double Calc = a * b;
  string Complete = "The answer is " + Calc;
  return Complete;
}
```

The JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Add() {
      var v1 = $get('TextA').value;
      var v2 = $get('TextB').value;
      CalculatorWebService.Add(v1, v2, ResultCallBack);
    }
    function Subtract() {
      var v1 = $get('TextA').value;
      var v2 = $get('TextB').value;
      CalculatorWebService.Subtract(v1, v2, ResultCallBack);
    }
    function Divide() {
      var v1 = $get('TextA').value;
      var v2 = $get('TextB').value;
      CalculatorWebService.Divide(v1, v2, ResultCallBack);
    }
    function Multiply() {
      var v1 = $get('TextA').value;
      var v2 = $get('TextB').value;
      CalculatorWebService.Multiply(v1, v2, ResultCallBack);
    }

    var DropDownSelection = document.getElementById('DropDownList1');

    switch (DropDownSelection.options[DropDownSelection.selectedIndex].value) {
      case "+":
        $addHandler($get('ButtonA'), 'click', Add);
        break;
      case "-":
        $addHandler($get('ButtonA'), 'click', Subtract);
        break;
      case "/":
        $addHandler($get('ButtonA'), 'click', Divide);
        break;
      case "*":
        $addHandler($get('ButtonA'), 'click', Multiply);
        break;
    }
    function ResultCallBack(result) {
      $get('TextA').value = result;
    }
</script>
```

To summarise, when I select an option within the DDL, the "selected" attribute is not applied to any option (other than the first default option) if I use an UpdatePanel, and so my code won't work. Have I misinterpreted how the UpdatePanel works?

Below is the section of my page source code where you can see that despite me selecting "/", it is not "selected".

```
    <div id="UpdatePanel1">
    <select name="DropDownList1" onchange="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;DropDownList1\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" id="DropDownList1">
      <option selected="selected" value="+">+</option>
      <option value="-">-</option>
      <option value="/">/</option>
      <option value="*">*</option>
    </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: I'm curious about why you are using an update panel.  It looks as if you're doing all your work through javascript.  What happens on the server side?

Comment: Also I'm not sure about that `switch` statement in your javascript.  Since you're not in a loop or an event handler, I suspect that's only going to set up a handler for whichever item is selected when the page loads in the browser.

Comment: @AnnL. I'm using the webmethod for the server side functionality, while trying to call the Web Service using JavaScript I can't get it to work with the update panel. It works perfectly without the update panel (including the switch statement)... I'm using the updatepanel to prevent a full page refresh but it seems to be not Refreshing the DDL at all when a different option is selected. Surely I'm just missing something?

Comment: The purpose of an update panel is to allow you to post information back to the server and change the appearance of the screen from the server side, without doing a full page refresh.  I don't see, though, that you even need to post back, given that all your server functionality is through the web methods.  That's why I'm questioning the need for an update panel. If you don't post back, you don't need an update panel.

Comment: @AnnL. Ah that makes sense, so an update panel is for served side only and not client side? So is there any way to refresh only the dropdownlist to update the "selected" attributed? Or would I need to use a htm standard drop down control rather than an aspx dropdown control? Thanks for responding by the way, I've been learning allot through trail and error recently!

Comment: Also the reason why I chose to use the aspx control is to potentially load the DDL options programmatically in the page load within: if (!Page.IsPostBack).

Comment: I think I may need some more context. If you want to change the `selected` attribute when the user picks a different option, you don't need to do that:  the act of selecting does that.  (But you won't see it as selected if you View Source, because that just reflects what came down from the server, not how you've changed things.  You'd need to use the browser's own tools to inspect the `select` element to see how it has changed.) But to answer the question, you absolutely can change the `selected` attribute via javascript, if that's what you want to do.

Comment: I'd have to look up some stuff to see how to do it with pure javascript, because I'm used to using jQuery.  It's been a while since I used pure javascript.

Comment: Did my questions and comments help you?  If so, please consider selecting my answer (which contains the same information  as the comments) as your accepted answer.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see that you even need an `UpdatePanel`.

The purpose of an update panel is to allow you to post information back to the server and change the appearance of the screen from the server side, without doing a full page refresh.

But if all your server functionality is through `Web Methods`, you don't need to post back at all.  You can react to the responses from the `Web Methods` and change the screen as needed, all through `javascript`.

To respond to another part of your question:  you don't need to involve the server to change which list item has the `selected` attribute in a `DropDownList` or HTML `select`.  You can do that in `javascript`.

But, if your user is selecting the items in the `DropDownList` or `select`, you don't even need to do that:  the act of selecting an item causes the `selected` attribute to be associated with the list item.

You won't see it, though, if you use the browser's View Source feature, because that only shows the code that came down from the server.  It doesn't reflect how the markup may have been changed.

If you want to be certain that the list item has the `selected` attribute, you need to use the browser's page inspection and debugging tools, which can be accessed with `F12` in IE or `Ctrl-Shift-I` in Chrome.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, sorry for late reply, you were right as I can see that the select control does update when I look at the browser's page inspection tool. I've selected your reply as the answer. I guess I will just have to accept that my code will work without an updatepanel, but won't work with the updatepanel. It's a little bit of a shame because if I ever wanted to utilise something like this without causing a full postback (using JS & WebMethods), it can't be done. Either use pure JS, or deal with a full postback